# Is there a 0-form $\tau$ with $d\tau=\omega$?

Tags: differential-geometry, integration

> > Consider the 1-form 
> >     $$
> > \omega=(x^2-yz)dx+(y^2-xz)dy-xydz.
> > $$
> >     Does a 0-Form $\tau$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$ exist which fullfils $d\tau=\omega$?

Hello, my simple answer is: YES, because on $\mathbb{R}^3$ there exists an antiderivative for $\omega$, because my calculations showed that $\omega$ is closed and furthermore $\mathbb{R}^3$ is path connected.

This antiderivative is a suitable 0-Form here.

Am I right with this argumentation?

Comment: You can easily check that $\tau = \frac{1}{3}x^3 + \frac{1}{3}y^3 - xyz + C$ satisfies that relationship.

Comment: Path connectedness isn't the relevant thing here. It's another property of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Do you mean "einfach zusammenhängend"? I do not know the english expression for that... but this follows from path connected...

Comment: Or do you mean that $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a star domain?

Comment: "Einfach zusammenhaengend" = "simply connected".  It does not follow from path-connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A standard multivariate calculus argument is as follows.

For $0$ form $\tau = \phi(x,y,z)$ so that $d\tau = \omega$, we just wanna find a $\phi$ satisfying:
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} = x^2−yz,
\\
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y} = y^2−xz,
\\
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z} =−xy.
$$
Integrating the first with respect to $x$ gives :
$$
\phi = \frac{x^3}{3} - xyz + g(y,z).
$$
Taking partial $y$:
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y} = −xz +\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} = -xz + y^2.
$$
Integrating $g$ with respect to $y$: 
$$
g = \frac{y^3}{3} + h(z) \implies \phi = \frac{x^3}{3} - xyz + \frac{y^3}{3} + h(z).
$$
Then taking derivative with respect to $z$ and find $h(z)$.

---

To translate Jared's answer, simply checking $\nabla \times (x^2−yz,y^2−xz,-xy) = 0$ in all $\mathbb{R}^3$ suffices to guarantee the existence of $\tau$.

Answer (score 3):

A cohomological argument: since $H^1(\mathbb{R}^3)=0$, any degree $1$ cocycle must be a degree $1$ coboundary.  If you've shown that $\omega$ is closed, it must be the coboundary of some $0$ form $\tau$.

Or, as suggested in the comments, you can just compute.

Comment: +1 very nice Jared. However, I know just the other answer.